# Can I use motion layout in production

Tags: android-motionlayout

I've written a UI component that uses motion layout (and it's dope). Some of my peers have concerns about using a beta dependency in production. Everything appears to be stable and working which begs the question why is there not a stable release of motion layout?

Does anyone use motion layout in a production app?

I am using this dependency

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you tested your custom UI component which relies on the `MotionLayout` and if it seems stable enough for you, then there is nothing stops you from using it in the production app. Since the `MotionLayout` is already in beta the API surface will not make any breaking changes in the upcoming beta/stable release. So you don't need to worry about anything if it already works well for you.

Go ahead, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think they are working on other support tools to make the development using motion layout easy. One such feature is to enable the UI design tab of Android studio showing animation/transition start to end. 
In addition to what Darish has mentioned. Make sure all other screens using Constraint layout tested. As the library contains optimisations/changes to existing constraint layout as well.